# Can I create a .NET Core Web API standalone app?

Tags: .net, publish, .net-core

I'm using .NET Core to create a web API.  Our tech lead kept on telling me that we can publish this as standalone.  This is what confuses me.  Can I really create a standalone build for a web API?  I thought these web APIs will run on the kestrel server thru IIS?

I've looked at the documentations and found nothing about this.

Really appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.
Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can build a standalone .NET Core web application.

It's important to define what "standalone" means in this context: a console-based application that, when run, self-hosts with Kestrel or another HTTP server like WebListener.

This is distinct from applications that are hosted on top of IIS, because that requires IIS to be running separately. Standalone/self-hosted applications don't need anything other than what they bring.

See the [Server documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, 'standalone' as in nothing needs to be installed on the target deployment machine.  So it is as what you described, a console app that runs, self hosts, etc.  That's what my tech lead is saying.  That way, it's easier to deploy and we can move the deployment to another similar spec'd machine, if need be.  I'll have a read at the link (thanks).  Also been playing around with the 'dotnet publish --configuration release --runtime win7-x64', but can't seem to get a dotnet.exe on the output files.  Do you know what I might be missing?

Comment: @james Not off the top of my head, but if you create a new question (including your `project.json` and anything relevant) and ping me here, I'd be happy to take a look. :)

Comment: Hi, Can my .net 8.0 application be published in self-contained mode and deployed on IIS?